# Заменить символ в строке по индексу

Tags: javascript

Имеется строка и индекс:

```
let str = 'abacaba'
let index = 2
```

Как можно изменить символ в строке по этому индексу?

Хочется что-нибудь вроде `str.replaceAt(index, 'x')`, где `'x'` это новый символ.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку метода для замены символа по индексу нет, ну и сами строки так изменять невозможно, то мы прибегаем к разбивке строки на подстроки.

Что бы заменить символ мы создаем метод для строк. Заменяем нужный элемент путем разбивания строки на подстроки - берем первую часть строки (до указанного индекса) и берем часть строки после указанного индекса и до конца строки. Между ними вставляем нужный элемент.

Этот метод будет работать на всех строках вашего проекта.

```js
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
  return this.substr(0, index) + replacement + this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

let str = 'abacaba';
let index = 2;
console.log(str.replaceAt(index, "x")); // Выведет abxcaba
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно сделать. Разделяем строку на две части до и после символа, и прикрепляем обратно с символом в промежутке.

```js
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, replacement) {
  return this.substr(0, index) + replacement+ this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}
var hello="Hello World";
console.log(hello.replaceAt(2, "!!")); //should display He!!o World
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Скопируй это
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, char) {
  return this.substr(0, index) + char + this.substr(index + 1, this.length);
};

let str = "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet", index = 3, char = "_";

document.getElementById("string").innerText = str;
document.getElementById("index").innerText = index;
document.getElementById("result_char").innerText = char;
document.getElementById("result").innerText = str.replaceAt(index, char);
```

```css
* {margin: 0;padding: 0;box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  background-color: #494D68;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    В стрке "<span id="string"></span>" символ на <span id="index"></span>
    месте заменяется на "<span id="result_char"></span>": "<span id="result"></span>"
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```